# Printing a pdf using PDFBox cuts the left side of pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

```
**We are using pdfbox.1.8.2. Below piece of code cuts the left side of pdf while printing    



    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
Paper paper = job.defaultPage().getPaper();
paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());
// custom page format
PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
pageFormat.setPaper(paper);
// override the page format
Book book = new Book();
// append all pages
book.append(new PDPageable(document), pageFormat, document.getNumberOfPages());
job.setPageable(book);
job.print();
```

> **It is not a receipt printer, pdf is printed using regular
>   printer.**
>
> Please advise how can I solve this issue.
>
> Thanks**

Comment: in the 2.0 version, do paper.setImageableArea(....). If your file is public, open an iissue in JIRA. Is it a PDF for a receipt printer?

Comment: Current version is 1.8.10, or 2.0 RC1. Did you try to set the first parameter of paper.setImageableArea to 1) a positive value (e.g. 50) or a 2) negative value (e.g. -50) and does this change anything ?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, nothing changed.It still cuts the left portion of the pdf.